# Can't map hidden items to javabean struts2

Tags: java, struts2

1. I have a dynamic form for user to input their education information. One user can have more than 1 education information. I used hidden field to store user's eduID. But it look like hidden field can't map to javabean item. When i submit form with existed item, that item's `ID` on server side always 0 instead of its actually `ID`
2. I want to provide user the ability to delete and undelete item. When user delete an item, i set all element with `display: none` and set a hidden field value to `true` (This hidden field is intend to let me know which item is deleted while iterating over the list). But when i submit form, deleted item in javabean list take null value.

So how can i map hidden element to javabean object or there's another way to implement my concept?

Here's my code:

jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-dojo-tags" prefix="sx"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>

<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="js/common.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Education List</title>
</head>
<body>
<s:form action="/save" method="POST">   
    <div class="educationForm">
        <c:if test="${ (not empty educations) }"> 
            <c:if test="${ fn:length(educations) ge 1 }">
                <c:forEach items="${educations}" var="edu" varStatus="status">
                    <div class="educations">    
                        <input type="hidden" name="education[${ status.index }].eduID" value="${ educations[status.index].index }" />               
                        <label>Position</label><input type="text" name="educations[${ status.index }].index" value="${ educations[status.index].index }" /> <a href="" class="delete">Delete</a><br/>
                        <label>School</label><input type="text" name="educations[${ status.index }].school" value="${ educations[status.index ].school }" /><br/>
                        <label>Degree</label><input type="text" name="educations[${ status.index }].degree" value="${ educations[status.index ].degree }" /><br/>
                        <label>GPA</label><input type="text" name="educations[${ status.index }].scored" value="${ educations[status.index ].scored }" /><br/>
                        <label>Start Date</label><input type="text" name="educations[${ status.index }].startDate" value="${ educations[status.index].startDate }" /><br/>
                        <label>End Date</label><input type="text" name="educations[${ status.index }].endDate" value="${ educations[status.index].endDate }" /><br/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="educations[${ status.index }].deleted" value="${ educations[status.index].deleted }" />
                    </div>
                </c:forEach>        
            </c:if>         
        </c:if>
        <div class="educations">
            <label>Position</label><input type="text" name="educations[${fn:length(educations)}].index" value="${fn:length(educations) + 1}" /><a href="" class="delete">Delete</a><br/>
            <label>School</label><input type="text" name="educations[${fn:length(educations)}].school" /><br/>
            <label>Degree</label><input type="text" name="educations[${fn:length(educations)}].degree" /><br/>
            <label>GPA</label><input type="text" name="educations[${fn:length(educations)}].scored" /><br/>
            <label>Start Date</label><input type="text" name="educations[${fn:length(educations)}].startDate" /><br/>
            <label>End Date</label><input type="text" name="educations[${fn:length(educations)}].endDate" /><br/>
            <input type="hidden" name="educations[${fn:length(educations)}].deleted" value="false" />
        </div>
    </div>  
    <a href="" id="addButton">Add new Edu</a>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />        
</s:form>

<div class="template_educations" style="display:none">
    <div class="educations">
        <label>Position</label><input type="text" name="educations[_X_].index" value="_Y_" /><a href="" class="delete">Delete</a><br/>
        <label>School</label><input type="text" name="educations[_X_].school" /><br/>
        <label>Degree</label><input type="text" name="educations[_X_].degree" /><br/>
        <label>GPA</label><input type="text" name="educations[_X_].scored" /><br/>
        <label>Start Date</label><input type="text" name="educations[_X_].startDate" /><br/>
        <label>End Date</label><input type="text" name="educations[_X_].endDate" /><br/>
        <input type="hidden" name="ducations[_X_].deleted" value="false" />
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //handle add new education
    $("#addButton").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        //append html inside template_educations div into educationForm div
        $(".educationForm").append($(".template_educations").html());

        //loop through input tag inside educations div
        $(".educationForm").children(".educations").last().children("input").each(function(){           
            var count = $(".educationForm").children(".educations").length;

            //replace value of position textfield with current position
            var value = $(this).attr("value");
            if(typeof value !== 'undefined' && value !== false)
            {
                value = value.replace("_Y_", count);
                $(this).attr("value", value);
            }

            //replace educations list index in textfield
            var name = $(this).attr("name");
            name = name.replace("_X_", count);
            $(this).attr("name", name);

        });         
    });

    //handle delete education
    $("body").on("click", ".delete", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        //hide all tag in education and set deleted to true
        var parent = $(this).parents(".educations");
        var hidden = parent.find("input[type=hidden]");
        hidden.val("true");
        parent.children().each(function(){
            if($(this) !== hidden)
            {
                $(this).hide();
            }           
        });

        //display undelete button
        parent.append("<a class='undelete' href=''>undelete</a>");
    });

    //handle undelete education
    $("body").on("click", ".undelete", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        //unhide all tag in parent and set deleted to false
        var parent = $(this).parents(".educations");
        var hidden = parent.find("input[type=hidden]");
        hidden.val("false");
        parent.children().each(function(){
            if($(this) !== hidden)
            {
                $(this).show();
            }           
        });

        //delete undelete button
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Action:

```
package com.education.actions;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Action;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Result;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Results;

import com.education.bean.Education;
import com.education.dao.DataConnectDao;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class SaveEdu extends ActionSupport 
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<Education> educations;

    public List<Education> getEducations() {
        return educations;
    }

    public void setEducations(List<Education> educations) {
        this.educations = educations;
    }   

    @Action(value="/save", results={
            @Result(name="success", type="redirect", location="/list.action"),
            @Result(name="input", type="redirect", location="/list.action")
            })

    public String execute()
    {
        DataConnectDao connect = new DataConnectDao();

        connect.insertDetailDao(this.educations);

        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

JavaBean:

```
package com.education.bean;

import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;

public class Education {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int eduID;
    private String school;
    private String degree;
    private float scored;
    private String startDate;
    private String endDate;
    private int index;
    private boolean deleted;

    public Education()
    {
        deleted = false;
    }

    public int getEduID() {
        return eduID;
    }
    public void setEduID(int eduID) {
        this.eduID = eduID;
    }
    public String getSchool() {
        return school;
    }
    public void setSchool(String school) {
        this.school = school;
    }
    public String getDegree() {
        return degree;
    }
    public void setDegree(String degree) {
        this.degree = degree;
    }
    public float getScored() {
        return scored;
    }
    public void setScored(float scored) {
        this.scored = scored;
    }
    public String getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }
    public void setStartDate(String startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }
    public String getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }
    public void setEndDate(String endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }
    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }
    public void setIndex(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    public boolean isDeleted() {
        return deleted;
    }

    public void setDeleted(boolean deleted) {
        this.deleted = deleted;
    }
}
```

Insert Data:

```
package com.education.serivces;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import com.education.bean.Education;
import com.education.utils.HibernateUltils;

public class DataConnect {
    Session sess;
    Transaction transaction;
    List<Education> educations;

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public void inserEducation(List<Education> edu)
    {
        try 
        {
            sess = HibernateUltils.getSession();

            transaction = sess.beginTransaction();

            for(Iterator<Education> educations = edu.iterator(); educations.hasNext();)
            {
                Education education = educations.next();

                sess.saveOrUpdate(education);
            }

            transaction.commit();   

        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            transaction.rollback();
            logger.error(e);            
        }
        finally
        {
            sess.close();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "finally" })
    public List<Education> getEducation()
    {               
        try
        {
            sess = HibernateUltils.getSession();

            sess.beginTransaction();

            Query query = sess.createQuery("from Education");       

            this.educations = (List<Education>) query.list();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            logger.error(e);    
        }
        finally
        {
            sess.close();
            return educations;          
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider using less code to illustrate your question.

Comment: I'm sorry, actually I don't know which part is wrong here so I tried to give everybody as much information as I can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you keep just one separate String variable on server side named indexesToRemove and map it to just one hidden value in your jsp.
It would have the values of deleted EduId's separated by some separator.

Ex: 2-5-8 would mean that EduID 2, 5 and 8 have to be removed from the list. 
Now every time user deletes/undeletes you can modify it's value using JS code.

Using this string value you can process your list on submit or some server side action as required.

Regarding the first part:
I am not aware of any limitation where hidden values can't be mapped to java bean properties. The issue I guess is that you have:

```
<input type="hidden" name="education[${ status.index }].eduID" value="${ educations[status.index].index }" />
```

Why is this not: `value="${ educations[status.index].eduID }"` ?

Comment: In theory, it would be ok, I'll give it a try. And do you have any ideas for `problem 1`? Whenever I tried to submit a form with existed item, that item's `ID` always 0.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I'm such a clumsy, thank you so much for pointed it out for me

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but it still doesn't fix the problem

Comment: I fixed it :D. I used `education` instead of `educations`, it's typo error :D